Romance movie about a posh husband and wife having a Chinese kid
Necessary points of detail:

It was a movie, not a TV show or in any series. It was in colour.
Film was in English, I believe it was from the USA because of the accent
I can't remember when I watched it and I can't remember when it was showing
Characters were I am sure of Caucasian ethnicity, a man who was very high class and spoke very posh and his wife who became pregnant to him

The one only scene I remember:
The above mentioned couple lived in an apartment that was very high up in a tall building, overlooking the city. The background of the city had a very modern look, tall buildings and it was very large (looked like New York). The scene was filmed in the 'night time'.
The two had a kid, they still had not named him. When the two were deciding on a name for their kid the woman suddenly said:

(Babie's name*, his name is Babie's name.

When she mentioned this, her husband looked down in surprise and pride and said:

I quite like that, I quite like that.

After this happened, the wife took the baby to the window overlooking the city and said:

Hello (Babie's name), this is your new home, welcome to the world.

The husband came and embraced her, she looked up to him in fondness. While this was happening, her husband put his hand on his wife's pregnant belly and said:

Hopefully this one doesn't come out looking Chinese.

The wife smiled and said:

Yeah, hopefully.

This is the only scene I remember, I do not remember much from it, I have provided as much detail as possible and in as much depth as I can.
I would very much like to know what film this is.

I know you said you don't remember when you watched it, but can you at least take a stab at a decade?

The decade yes I can, I watched it this decade, somewhere early this decade.

I disagree with the off-topic close vote, because this is purely about a movie identification.

@natural You might very well have missed that not all identification questions are on-topic here: Identification questions must contain sufficient detail to meet the site's quality standards. They should be about identifying an actor, movie, TV show, or a specific episode of a TV show and should not consist only of an image. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions. You might want to argue that it does show enough detail and effort, but the sole fact of it being an identification question does not automatically make it appropriate.

I'm sure I'm wrong, but some of your description matches an experimental horror film, titled Antichrist from Lars Van Trier about the mental collapse of woman who looses her baby after it falls from a balcony window. The couple/parents retreat to a cabin to recover, but it ultimately brings out the worst...

@DarthLocke No, it's not it, but it sure looks interesting though.
